# Inconsistent build behaviours in Rust on macOS Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust and have been following the Rust book tutorials. A lot of the times when I try to run a project it seems to compile but doesn't run.

Here is an example when I try to run the first part of the program for the [guessing game](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html):

```
$ cargo run --verbose                                                                     (master✱)
       Fresh guessing_game v0.1.0 (/Users/rohana/Documents/Projects/rust/guessing_game)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s
     Running `target/debug/guessing_game`
[1]    30294 killed     cargo run --verbose
```

However the same code will sometimes run if I make any changes like adding comments, then running and reverting and running again. Not always though.

I am using Rust 1.31.1 and Cargo 1.31.0 on macOS Mojave 10.14.2.

This is the code for reference, but the same problem also occurs on a blank "Hello World!" program:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number");
    println!("Please enter your guess");
    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed {}", guess);
}
```

Comment: I have the same environment, executed this bash: `for i in {1..200}; do echo "//--" >> src/main.rs; cargo run --verbose;  done` , but couldn't reproduce your error.

Comment: The message "killed" is suspicious. Since you did not kill the process, something else must have. Maybe your system is very low on memory, and the kernel is killiing the Cargo process?

Comment: I don't think so. I have 16 gb out of 8 will be free

Comment: Try running the compiled binary in a debugger. For example, `lldb target/debug/guessing_game`. Once in LLDB, type `run`. Hopefully, this will generate an error and you will be returned to the LLDB prompt. Once there, type `bt`. Copy and paste all that output here.

Comment: @Shepmaster I tried that but it hangs on run and returns `error: process exited with status -1 (unable to attach)`